# Can I use "a" with the word single

Tags: word-usage, indefinite-article

As I understand, single (sometimes) means one. For example, single pair of shoes or single parameter an so on. My question is can I use "a" with "single". For example,

*This shows only a single type of correlation*.

Is that correct? if not, then, why?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes. "Single" is used as an adjective here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Articles like "the" or "a" are used with nouns.  "Single" is most commonly used an adjective, and is only a noun in a [few limited contexts](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/single).

In your example, the noun is "type", and what matters is if whether you make it singular or plural, "type" or "types".  The adjective "single" doesn't make any difference.  Example:

> This graph shows **a** single **point** of intersection between the two functions.
>
> This graph shows multiple **points** of intersection between the two functions.

Naturally, it would be weird to say something like:

> This graph shows a single **points** of ...

For general interest, here are a couple of examples using "single" as a noun:

> The Beatles' song "Hey Jude" was first released as **a single** in 1968
>
> It's not easy living as **a single** in the big city.
>
> Late in the eighth inning the batter hit **a** lazy **single** to shallow right field, driving home the go-ahead run.

Comment: The question is a yes/no question. Unfortunately, the answer isn't very clear.